# Trouble dual booting Win 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.3 on two separate drives

Tags: dual-boot

Set up Win 10 on 500 GB NVME drive. It worked fine. Then set up Ubuntu on a different HDD (1 1 TB HDD). Ubuntu install went well and it worked fine. However after going into the UEFI and switching the boot drive back to 500 GB NVME, Windows 10 no longer boots. I get a blank screen with flashing cursor.

If I reset UEFI Back to 1 TB HDD (Ubuntu drive) Ubuntu works fine again. I tried to look at Grub during the boot process, I don't see any reference to Windows.

I think Windows is intact but the boot loader may have been corrupted by Grub.I looked at the drive through GParted and the partitions look normal.

Suggestions on how to fix this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: sorry to be pedantic but there is no version 20 unless you are referring to core. Please [edit] your question with correct and complete details of your version of ubuntu.

Comment: For problems such as this, [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is usually the program to use.  Perhaps you can give it a try?

Comment: And you need to understand UEFI boot process. It doesn't rely on "drives" unlike the old BIOS. The drive conatining the ESP (EFI System Partition) should *always* be the first in order. OSes are selected in another settings in UEFI > Boot.

Comment: I will be giving boot repair a try.

Comment: ChanganAuto, can you provide specific recommendation of what I should try?

Comment: Post the link to the report that Boot-Repair gives in your question above. Then we can make better suggestions on fixes as we will know the details of your installs. With two drives, best to not run any auto fix. You normally then use the Advanced mode for fixes.